# Network namespace as a regular user

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, namespace, network-namespaces

In linux you can create network namespaces, using the `ip` command. But you need to be root to run that command. However you can still create network namespaces as a regular user using `unshare -rUn`. With this command, the new network namespace will be owned by a restricted user namespace.

With a new network namespace i can't connect to internet. Creating a veth pair requires root, is there a way to allow my network namespace to connect to the internet without root?. I know that many features like sharing the physical network with the namespace would not be possible. Can you create virtual interfaces like `tun0` in a restricted network namespace.

With a network namespace owned by a regular user, you can for example run openvpn without root.

```
$ create-network-namespace
$ openvpn home.ovpn
$ google-chrome
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, there already exists a project on github which creates a virtual tap device in the namespace and uses the socket syscall in the host namespace. Every packet sended through TAP will be transformed to a socket operation.

https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns